# Implementing the d3 start event listener

Tags: d3.js

It appears that I don't quite understand how event listeners in d3 work.

As an example, let's create an svg element, and then create a circle in the svg container:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("height", svgHeight)
        .attr("width", svgWidth);

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 100)
    .attr("cy",100)
    .attr("r", 40)
    .style("fill", "black");
```

The circle currently has a radius of 40px.

I want to implement a transition on the circle, where at the start of the transition I change its radius to 80px, and then decrease it to 20 points.

Why doesn't this work?

```
d3.select("circle")
.transition()
.delay(750)
.duration(1000)
.each("start", function() {d3.select(this).attr("r", 80);  }  )
.attr("r", 20)
```

Comment: works pretty much as per your expectations https://jsfiddle.net/1n4wn2d3/ don't see anything strange. First it becomes radius 80 then it transitions to 20. The radius 80 will be set after 750 milliseconds and the transition from 80 to 20 will take 1 second.

Comment: that's bizarre. It works up there on jsfiddle, but when I copy paste your code and try it myself, all I see is the circle decreasing from 40 to 20

Comment: which version are you using? in the fiddle it is the latest..

Comment: yep - that was it. I was accidentally linking to an old version. Thanks for the help!